# replace the numerical value with another value in each line when some text is matched

Tags: python, awk, sed, scripting, gawk

I have a large file and want to process the numerical values on each line if some text is matched on the corresponding line. For example if I have the following lines in a large text file:

```
system.membus.respLayer1.occupancy              55000                       # Layer occupancy (ticks)
system.membus.respLayer1.utilization              5.5                       # Layer utilization (%)
system.l2.prefetcher.prefetcher.num_hwpf_identified            0                       # number of hwpf identified
```

I want to replace `55000` with with its doubled value and `5.5` with its half value if the text at the beginning of each line is matched. These values may vary for different files, i.e. `55000` and `5.5` are not fixed.
Can anyone please help me how to achieve this using `Python, sed, awk`,etc

Comment: Is this a fixed width file? Also, what code have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: awk seems the way to go. Try: `awk '/occu/{$2=$2*2}/util/{$2=$2/2}1'`

Comment: Could also use `$2 *= 2` and `$2 /= 2` respectively. And I would be more explicitly about matching: `$1 == "system.membus.respLayer1.occupancy" {$2 *= 2} $1 == "system.membus.respLayer1.utilization" {$2 /= 2}`

Comment: Thanks dear @CasimiretHippolyte, it works but it removes all the spaces in between, like:  
system.membus.reqLayer0.occupancy 14000 # Layer occupancy (ticks)
system.membus.reqLayer0.utilization 0.35 # Layer utilization (%)

This file is to be passed to some other tool and formatting needs to be same. only numerics should be processed.

Comment: Thanks dear @glennjackman, but awk '$1 == "system.membus.respLayer1.occupancy" {$2 *= 2} $1 == "system.membus.respLayer1.utilization" {$2 /= 2}' file.txt is not giving any output. Is there anything missing?

Comment: You can also use perl in command line: `perl -pe's/occu\D*\K[.\d]+/$&*2/e;s!util\D*\K[.\d]+!$&/2!e' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/occupancy/   {sub($2,$2*2)} 
       /utilization/ {sub($2,$2/2)}1' file

    system.membus.respLayer1.occupancy              110000                       # Layer occupancy (ticks)
    system.membus.respLayer1.utilization              2.75                       # Layer utilization (%)
    system.l2.prefetcher.prefetcher.num_hwpf_identified            0                       # number of hwpf identified
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, Can I multiply some random value instead of 2?

Comment: Sure. Look up [`rand()` in the gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html#Numeric-Functions)

Comment: Thanks dear. If I use rand() in the above AWK, it prints the output as power of 10. like 1.46055e+06. Is it possible to avoid this notation and print as normal decimal values.

Comment: I think easiest will be changing to `$2=sub($2,sprintf("%d",$2/2))` in the block, similarly for multiplication.